# How to access Outer class Instance?

Tags: java

I've static nested class like below

```
public class AbstractClass {
    
    String AbstractClass = "AbstractClass";
    
    AbstractClass(){
        
        System.out.println("default constructor");
    }
    
    AbstractClass(String inp){
        
        this.AbstractClass = inp;
        System.out.println(this.AbstractClass);
    }

}

-----

public class MyClass {

     String MyClassVrbl = "MyClass";

    public static class Builder extends AbstractClass {
        
        String staticclassVrbl = "staticclassVrbl";

        Builder() {

        }

        Builder(String inp) {
            super(inp);
            System.out.println("custom construtor");

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        MyClass.Builder mc = new MyClass.Builder("calling custom");
        System.out.println(mc.how can access outer class instance variable..?);
        

    }

}
```

Once nested class(Builder) instance is created, parent(`MyClass`) must be instantiated too..right ? How can I access outer class instance out of `mc` to access `MyClassVrbl` ?

Is isnt it strange if `MyClass` is not instantiated even after creating nested `Builder` class ?

Answer (score 1):

> Once nested class(Builder) instance is created, parent(MyClass) must be instantiated too..right ?

That's not the case because the nested class is static. If it were an inner non-static class, then there would be an instance of the outer class associated with it. So the answer is you can't get the outer instance because it does not exist.

**Static nested class:**

```
public class MyClass {

   public static class Builder {

       Builder() {
           MyClass outerInstance = MyClass.this; // does not compile
       }

   }
}
```

**Non-static nested class (aka inner class):**

```
public class MyClass {


   public class Builder {

       Builder() {
           MyClass outerInstance = MyClass.this; // ok
       }

   }
}
```

Besides, when using the [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) you probably want to access the created instance using a `build()` method.

Comment: Isnt it something wrong about it ? Because, even if its static, its part of outer class. So outer must come into existence automatically, the moment static nested instantiated... No ? anything wrong into that ?

Comment: @Tim It's part of the outer class, but not the outer class _instance_. That's what the `static` keyword is all about.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access `myClassVrbl` using `mc`, because `mc` is an object of `Builder` which is a subclass of `AbstractClass`. You can access members of `AbstractClass`, but not of `MyClass`. Instantiating a `Builder` class object calls its super class constructor, not the one within which it is nested.